# Can I have an Array of regular expressions in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, automated-tests

for example:

```
record= [#data retrieved from database]
expect=~ [/^69[0-9]*/, /^[0-9]*/, /^[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*/, /^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}/]

if(record[0]== expect[0])
  puts("Pass")
else
  puts("Fail")
end
```

If there is a more sophisticated way please let me know but I also would like to know if a method like this works for reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I have an Array of regular expressions in ruby?

Yes.

> If there is a more sophisticated way [to test that a given string matches all regex]?

Use `Enumerable#all?`.

```
patterns = [/foo/, /bar/]
input = 'baz'
patterns.all? { |pattern| pattern.match?(input) }
```

`match?` was added recently, in ruby 2.4.

Comment: Additionally, if you have a few cases with different regexes, you can list them in the `when` clause.

Comment: Awesome Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately my job uses Ruby 2.3.3 is there a equivalent method to ".match?" in this version?

Comment: Re: "Unfortunately my job uses Ruby 2.3.3 is there a equivalent method to ".match?" in this version?" - Answer: no, but you can use `=~` instead

Comment: @JaredBeck I think in this case it should be `patterns.any?` , otherwise *all* regexes would need to match for this to return true.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out `===` operator which when following a regular expression literal allows you to compare against a String.

```
/^[a-z]*$/ === "HELLO" #=> false
/^[A-Z]*$/ === "HELLO" #=> true
```

But me also would suggest to check the docs for `=~`.